# signal spacebar key stroke on xte?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have been using xte for some UI testing and I found that `xte 'key Space'` doesn't seem to do much. How can I signal a spacebar key stroke on xte (Linux)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str`, like so:

```
xte 'str  '
```

EDIT: Although `xte 'key space'` is working for me too.